# How to construct js object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have some problems with React and Advertisement.
Wanna use 'Coupang' Advertisement, but they support the script library only.
I can add it to 'index.html' in the public directory, but cannot customize the location.

here is the code,

```
<script src="https://ads-partners.coupang.com/g.js"></script>
<script>
    new PartnersCoupang.G({"id":23232,"subId":null});
</script>
```

It's a dynamic advertisement.
How can I add it to the React functional component??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MB this will be helpful.

[useScript](https://usehooks.com/useScript/) will help you add script to your code dynamically.

and you custom hook (just create `PartnersCoupang`);

```
const usePartnersCoupang = () => {
  const const [loaded, error] = useScript('https://ads-partners.coupang.com/g.js');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      new PartnersCoupang.G({"id":23232,"subId":null});
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('PartnersCoupang Failed.');
    }
  }, [error]);
}
```

Comment: How can I create 'PartnerCoupang'?

Comment: '/src/client/js/usePartnerCoupang.js
  Line 8:42:  'PartnersCoupang' is not defined  no-undef' still cant find the Object...hmm..

Comment: Because it is global variable. It is ESLint warning.

Comment: Code sandbox is just example and it works. Script is added to the page and global variable is available into react project. If you have ESLint in your own project ad `PartnerCoupang` to global variable

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand... My coupang ID is 'new PartnersCoupang.G({"id":217462,"subId":null});' and it should show the moving pictures when I add it.. How can I add it in your example??

Comment: Sorry, I don't familiar with PartnersCoupang and I didn't find English documentation for it. You asked How to load script and create `new PartnersCoupang.G`. And I have shown how. In codesandbox `usePartnersCoupang` returns created object. Feels free to play with codesandbox. Change `usePartnersCoupang.js` if you want to change `{ id":217462,"subId":null }`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should `eject` from your `create-react-app` project by this command:

```sh
$ yarn eject
```

or:

```sh
$ npm run eject
```

Then you can see a folder that name is `config`, in this folder you can see all configuration of your project, especially your Webpack configs, then you should add your external library to the webpack as `external` key on the configuration of Webpack:

```js
// webpack.config.js
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    externals: {
        PartnersCoupang: '[path-to]/g.js',
    },
    ...
};
```

Then in your component import it easily:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PartnersCoupang from 'PartnersCoupang';

class YourComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    new PartnersCoupang.G({"id":23232,"subId":null});
  }
}
```

Comment: I did eject and found webpack.config.js, but when I add externals it says "Unnecessary label externals". And what should I put instead of ${srcRoot} ??

Comment: @Johnkim, You should write your path to the `g.js` file. download it and put it on your project. somewhere you want it. then in webpack externals, guide it to the true path. the `externals` key should be the root of `module.exports` object.

Comment: Where should I put 'externals' in webpack.config.js ??

Comment: @Johnkim, Read this like. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/